# SQL Left Join Only One Row

Tags: mysql, sql

By using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT pictures.IMAGELINK,userdata.BIRTHDATE,userdata.POSITION,InfiniteLove.USERNAME FROM 
InfiniteLove
LEFT JOIN pictures ON InfiniteLove.USERNAME = pictures.USERNAME
LEFT JOIN userdata ON InfiniteLove.USERNAME = userdata.USERNAME
WHERE NOT InfiniteLove.USERNAME = '".$USERNAME."' AND InfiniteLove.GENDER = 
'M' AND InfiniteLove.SEARCH = 'M' OR InfiniteLove.SEARCH = 'B'
```

I get this result:

[image]

The Problem is, that I only want ONE row from each user.
But when the user has more than one picture it is showing multiple rows.

What can I do, that I get only one row from each user?

Thanks

Comment: If the user has multiple pictures and you only want one, which one do you want?

Comment: The first one, it's not very important which one but when then the first.

Comment: add `GROUP BY InfiniteLove.USERNAME`

Comment: Got it, thanks. Would like to accept your answer, post it as answer? Maybe with why is it working

Comment: @J.Doe If the picture isn't that important why bother including it in the output at all? If it is important, you can include all of the values in your output with GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @Paul I just need one picture

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry your comment did not helped in any way. Wish I could downvote you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT pictures.IMAGELINK,userdata.BIRTHDATE,userdata.POSITION,InfiniteLove.USERNAME FROM 
InfiniteLove
LEFT JOIN pictures ON InfiniteLove.USERNAME = pictures.USERNAME
LEFT JOIN userdata ON InfiniteLove.USERNAME = userdata.USERNAME
WHERE NOT InfiniteLove.USERNAME = '".$USERNAME."' AND InfiniteLove.GENDER = 
'M' AND InfiniteLove.SEARCH = 'M' OR InfiniteLove.SEARCH = 'B'
GROUP BY InfiniteLove.USERNAME
```

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, this simply returns an indeterminate result set, which is at best misleading.

Comment: Since he doesn't care about the result (which picture) it doesn't matter if the picture in indeterminate, what matters is 1 row per user